# Запись в файл /data/data/x.x/lib/lib.so с правами суперпользоыателя

Tags: android, файлы, su

Всем здравствуйте. Я использую [LibInjector](https://github.com/jbro129/LibInjector) чтобы заменять хексы оффсетов на другие, не для своего приложения, а для других.

В LibInjector есть этот код:

```
raf = new RandomAccessFile(libPath, "rw");
```

который позволяет выбрать файл. При попытке указать файл и заменить хекс, я сталкиваюсь с ошибкой **Permission Denied**.

Я предоставлял приложению права суперпользователя, но это не работает.

Также я менял права файла lib.so

```
su -c chmod 777 /data/..
```

но это тоже не работает.

Возможно ли это сделать, и как?

(Желательно без копирования файла в другие места)

Answer (score 0):

Если файл в root директории то из программ линух нехотя дает их изменять(консоль не считается). Переместите в home директорию желательно. Я сам не лучшим образом знаю линукс так что это ответ на моем опыте только.

Comment: Я делаю андроид приложение. Я не понимаю, как проводникам удается изменять файл, а моему приложению нет?